# resize multiple iframes to current window size

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard that resides inside a content management system.  It has 4 iframes arranged in a table so that 3 frames occupy the first column and 3 seperate rows.  The 4th frame occupies the second column and spans all three rows.  Javascript gets the window dimensions and resizes the frames onload() and onresize().  On a small sized window the 3 frames on the left column all size themselves a half inch tall even though there is visible room for them.

What is throwing of the vertical sizing and how can i improve it?

Please focus answers on the javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var winW = 1024, winH = 768; //This sets a minimum height and width
    function calcHeight(ifid) {
        getWinH();
        document.getElementById(ifid).height = winH;
    }
    //Cross-browser function to get window height

       var compW = 35;
       var compH = 290;

        function getWinH() {

        if (document.body &amp;&amp; document.body.offsetWidth) {
            winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
            winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }
        if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' &amp;&amp; document.documentElement &amp;&amp; document.documentElement.offsetWidth) {
            winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
            winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        }
        if (window.innerWidth &amp;&amp; window.innerHeight) {
            winW = window.innerWidth;
            winH = window.innerHeight;
        }
          winW = winW - compW;
          winH = winH - compH;  

    document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("width", Math.floor(winW * 0.4));
    document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("height", Math.floor(winH * 0.4));

    document.getElementById("box4").setAttribute("width", Math.floor(winW * 0.6));
    document.getElementById("box4").setAttribute("height", winH + 175); //comps for the titles of other boxes

    document.getElementById("box2").setAttribute("width", Math.floor(winW * 0.4));
    document.getElementById("box2").setAttribute("height", Math.floor(winH * 0.4));

    document.getElementById("box3").setAttribute("width", Math.floor(winW * 0.4));
    document.getElementById("box3").setAttribute("height", Math.floor(winH * 0.4));

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size with style:

```
 var boxes = [document.getElementById("box1"), document.getElementById("box2"), document.getElementById("box3"), document.getElementById("box4")];
boxes[0].style.width = Math.floor(winW * 0.4) + "px";
boxes[0].style.height =  Math.floor(winH * 0.4) + "px"

boxes[3].style.width = Math.floor(winW * 0.6) + "px";
boxes[3].style.height =  (winH + 175) + "px"; //comps for the titles of other boxes

boxes[1].style.width = Math.floor(winW * 0.4) + "px";
boxes[1].style.height = Math.floor(winH * 0.4) + "px";

boxes[2].style.width = Math.floor(winW * 0.4) + "px";
boxes[2].style.height = Matth.floor(winH * 0.4) + "px";
```

Comment: I changed it over to styles as you suggested it still behaves the same way.

Comment: I have a similar 4 x 4 grid that resizes itself perfectly.  Is the difference in the size calculations?